# lvalue initialization fails

Tags: c++, string, gcc, c++11

Some sample code from the "The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition" makes me confusing. Here is my test cases.

**Env** gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) with -std=c++0x

- **Code1** `string var {"Cambridge"}; string& r1 {var};` **Compiling fails**
- **Code2** `string var {"Cambridge"}; string& r1 = var;` **Compiling Succeed**
- **Code3** `string var {"Cambridge"}; string&& r1 {var};` **Compiling Succeed**
- **Code1 Compiling Fails with** `g++ -g -DLINUX -std=c++0x   -c src/dummy.cpp -o src/dummy.o
  src/dummy.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  src/dummy.cpp:26:17: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’
  make: *** [src/dummy.o] Error 1`
- Code1 should be ok according the books. Section 7.7.2 since var is a lvalue, but why code1 does not work but code3 works in my situation?

Comment: Looks like a bug in GCC (including 4.8), Clang accepts version 1 just fine.

Comment: You ran into [DR1288](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288). Hopefully, more recent compilers will implement the proposed resolution instead of the Standardized defect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because it tries to bind an rvalue to an nonconst lvalue reference.

> 8.5.4 List-initialization
>
> [#3]
>
> -- Otherwise, if T is a reference type, a **prvalue temporary** of the type
>   referenced by T is list-initialized, and the **reference is
>   bound to that temporary**. [ Note: As usual, the    binding will fail
>   and the program is ill-formed if the reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. — end note]

Check this example to verify that `r1` is bound to a distinct object

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int
main () {
  std::string var {"Cambridge"};
  const std::string& r1 {var}; 
  const std::string& r2 (var);

  var.clear ();

  std::cout << "var = " << var << std::endl;
  std::cout << "r1 = " << r1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "r2 = " << r2 << std::endl;
}
```

and contrast that to `r2`.

PS. Now the question arises, why the following does not fail according to the above considerations:

```
int x;
int &y { x };
```

the standard says (in the same place as above, but the next clause):

> -- Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element, the object or **reference** is initialized from that element;

This clause explicitly mentions reference, in other words, initializing a reference is not described in a single clause, but there are a few possibilities (maybe tried in order of the clauses?), which explains why `int &` behaves this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So does that mean the code of the book is wrong? It was trying to say this is a right demo code `string& r1{var}; //lvalue reference, bind r1 to var(an lvalue)` Section 7.7.2 of the book

Comment: Could you please give me some information about your compiler? Did you get the same "Compiling Error" with your example code compiling?

Comment: GCC 4.8.1 used here. Yes, I think the book is in error and there's another one there `string&& rr2 {var};` should work.

Comment: I have not get it yet. If you replace the "string" with "int" in code1, then it works. Following this logic, we would have a conclusion that "var is lvalue(int var {1}" and var is rvalue(string var {"abcd"}.

Comment: The rules of the language are different for different types, e.g. `int` is not a class type. I'm afraid you'd need to check the C++ Standard, Section 8.5.4 [#3], it's a bit too long to reproduce here, but you can read the draft for the next standard here, http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf , it's the same. But, indeed, I'd have to check with `int &`. Hang on ...

Comment: From my current point of view, the code1 is right. Reasons 1. Daniel Frey said it works Clang. 2. val should be lvalue whatever it is decleared as int or string from the c++ literal.

Comment: Check addition to the answer. And, no, implementations are not definitions of the language.

Comment: Thanks for your patient reply. Do you agree that "var" is lvalue in code1? You can do val = "bcd" after the definition. Then what is the problem of initializing a reference with a lvalue, it should just works.

Comment: There's been a change between n3242 and n3337 (between which the Standard has been released). In n3242, the first quote reads "Otherwise, if `T` is a reference to class type or if `T` is any reference type and the initializer list has no
elements" which wouldn't apply to `int&`. (Also, the whole issue is related to [DR1288](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288).)

Comment: This answer does not explain the behavior. In particular `int &y { x };` is handled by the 'Otherwise, if T is a reference type,' bullet, and not by the following 'Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element,'.

Comment: This answer should reference DR1288 as pointed out by DyP and note that this behavior is a bug in the standard.